# Extjs Numberfield discards leading zero

Tags: extjs

I have Extjs Numberfield in my form and this needs to send the number just like the user types it in. The number is an serial number of an ID Card, in this case I need the leeding zeros. But the Numberfield discards all zeros in front an begins with the first number unequal zero.
How can I change this?

Regards,
Prasath M

Comment: you should accept an answer if it was helpful for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use a `textfield` with a custom [validator](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.VTypes) so you can only insert numbers, cause ExtJS will store the value of a `numberfield` as an integer and a integer has no leading zeros.